# Web Service - File Not Found Exception in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to read a file using a web method

```
  [WebMethod]
        public string getjson()
        {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText("vision.json");
            return contents;

        }
```

I have logged in to the ftp account provided in Azure Portal and uploaded the file.
[image]

But File not found exception is thrown

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Could not find file 'D:\Windows\system32\vision.json'.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path to the json file.

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%HOME%\site\wwwroot\vision.json")
```